# How to perform a check on an object key and replace its value?

Tags: javascript

I have an object in form of:

```
let serviceData = [{title: "Template 1", note: "One time fee", usd: "200", eur: "185", gbp: "165"},
{title: "Template 2", note: "Monthly", usd: "200", eur: "185", gbp: "165"},
{title: "Template 3", note: "One time fee", usd: "200", eur: "185", gbp: "165"}]
```

What's the standard way to perform a check on the key `note` to see if it's equal to `monthly` or not, and if it is to replace the value of `usd` by multiplying it by 12 and returning the updated object?

Comment: "its value" as in what? `usd`, `eur`, and `gbp`? Why do you even store all three properties when there should be a fixed conversion between them? Why are they all strings instead of numbers?

Comment: Updated, "its value" = "usd". Yes, they should be numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through and modify the objects in place:

```js
for (const obj of serviceData) {
    if (obj.note === "Monthly") {
        obj.usd *= 12;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to clobber the original array, you can make a copy by `map`ping it:

```js
const modifiedData = serviceData.map(obj => {
    if (obj.note === "Monthly") {
        return {...obj, note: obj.note * 12};
    }
    return {...obj};
});
```

This utilizes [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).